# How can I use items displayed in the bottom-left on PC?

Tags: pc, naruto-ultimate-ninja

I am playing **Naruto Ultimate Ninja Storm 3 Full Burst**. 
As you know, this is is part of **Naruto Ultimate Ninja Storm 3** and it was on Xbox 360 and mine is PC version but still their key setting are same as Xbox 360.

As you see in image, I want to know how to use marked elements
[image]

These are the key setting of game.

Start (Enter)

Back (Backspace)

Y (A)

A (S)

X (D)

B (F)

Left stick click (Delete)

Right stick click (Insert)

Left Back (Q)

Right Back (W)

Left Trigger (Z)

Right Trigger (X)

Left Stick UP (Up Arrow)

Left Stick Down (Down Arrow)

Left Stick Left (Left Arrow)

Left Stick Right  Right Stick UP (NumberPad8)

Right Stick Down  Right Stick Left (NumberPad4)

Right Stick Right (NumberPad6)

DPAD Up (I)

DPAD Down (K)

DPAD Left (J)

DPAD Right (L)

*Thanks in Advance*

Comment: Did you try the keys tied to the DPAD (I, K, J, L)?

Comment: Doesn't the game have any sort of tutorial?

Comment: Oh!!! These were the only keys left. It is working. Thanks @Batophobia

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your comment, the way to use items tied to the DPAD (i.e. the items displayed in the lower left corner of the display) is to use the mappings you mentioned:

```
Controller    |  Key
--------------+-------
 DPAD Up      |   I
 DPAD Down    |   K
 DPAD Left    |   J
 DPAD Right   |   L
```